# Wrong calculation on Configurable product when Child product price is minus

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, special-price

I have set for a configurable product a base price of 150. One child product with another color is 50 less so I made it -50 at the attributes (associated products)

I have discounted the product with 15% and set as "Special Price". On the product page others looks good except the product with -50 shows as new price 77.50 while it should be 85.

It makes a wrong calculation as follows:

150-15%=150-22.50=127.50aed (configurable product)
100-15%=100-15=85aed it shows 77.50 (Child Product -50)

Why? it takes the discount of the mother product. 100-22.50=77.50

How can I solve this?

Comment: I would set lowest price to parent product and then add remaining for each child product.